# cuspidal kernel function

Tags: automorphic-forms

Let $G$ be a reductive group over some number field $F$ and $\pi$ an irreducible cuspidal automorphic representation of $G(\mathbb{A}_F)$. Let $f$ be a compactly supported function on $G(\mathbb{A}_F)$. Let
\begin{equation}
K_\pi (x, y) = \sum_{ \varphi } \pi(f) \varphi(x) \overline{\varphi(y)}
\end{equation}
with $x, y \in G(\mathbb{A}_F)$, and the sum is over an orthonormal basis of $\pi$. Then is it necessarily true that this is a finite sum? If not, why is it convergent?

Comment: Why do you know that it is convergent, if you don't know a proof?

Answer (score 1):

Given an irreducible cuspidal automorphic represnetation, then it has character, i.e. the following operator is trace class
$$ \pi(f) : v \mapsto \int\limits_{G(A)} f(g) \pi(g) v.$$
Note that 
$$ tr \pi(f) =  \sum\limits <v, \pi(f) v> $$
of course. So this guarantees convergence. Now, if you assume that $f$ is smooth in the sense that it is invariant from the right and the left by an irreudicble representation of a maximal compact subgroup it will indeed be a finite sum for an apropriately chosen basis. These project onto the corresponding $K$-type. Automorphic representations factor into local smooth admissible representations.  I am not so sure why your using functions instead of vectors.